# How to fix an error occurred while processing this directive in php website

Tags: php, .htaccess, server

Recently I migrate my php website from justhost to godaddy afterthen I changed in A record point section godaddy server ip.

after few I getting error [an error occurred while processing this directive] to all php webpages
after I approach to godaddy support they did changes from there end. Now only Website Home page working remaining all pages it showing error [an error occurred while processing this directive]. they told me there is a multiple .htaccess files.

I removed multiple .htaccess files.

exist this code in .htaccess file

```
# Use PHPBETA as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-phpbeta .php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.ptetests.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
    
    
</IfModule>
```

May I know this is the correct/not I need add which .htaccess file need to add to this site [ptetests.com](https://www.ptetests.com/)

and is there any changes I need to do please help on it.

Thank you in advance for your help and consideration

Comment: Whether your `.htaccess` file is correct or not depends on what you are trying to do. (There's nothing syntactically wrong with it.) Are you sure your `.htaccess` file is doing anything? The directive to "remove trailing slashes" doesn't appear to be doing anything. Are `.htaccess` overrides enabled? Is mod_rewrite enabled?

Comment: Are you using server-side-includes? The error you are seeing seems to be a 404 response `<!-- SHTML Wrapper - 404 Not Found -->`?